# Android JNI architecture target for use with multiple devices

Tags: android, ffmpeg, java-native-interface

When using JNI in Android does the C code need to be compiled to adhere to all different types of ARM architectures? For instance if I compile ffmpeg for armeabi can I use it on all Android devices or do I need to compile it to different targets such as armeabi-v7a?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Having

```
APP_ABI := armeabi armeabi-v7a x86
```

inside your Application.mk will create 3 .so files which are bundled with your apk file. This should cover all relevant android devices out there. No extra work needed from us developers.

As to your question: if you compile for armeabi your app will work for both armeabi and armeabi-v7a.  Thats because the latter is an extension of armeabi.
You can find a detailed explanation inside ndk.dir/docs/CPU-ARCH-ABIS.html.

Comment: Yes, but that's not quite the question that was asked.

Comment: What types of Android devices are x86?